# Resizing uploaded file and saving with the same name in the same location

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I try to save an image and resize with Intervention. Filesystem.php has default settings for Laravel 10.

I can successfully save under storage/app/public/image:

```
$file->storeAs('public/image/', $uniqueFileName);
```

Than I try to resize and save with same name.

```
$manager = new ImageManager();
$resizedImage = $manager->make(storage_path('app/public/image/' . $uniqueFileName))->resize(100, 100);
Storage::disk('public')->put(storage_path('public/image/' . $uniqueFileName), $resizedImage);
```

The problem is, last line creates such a folder and tries to save under this location:

```
/storage/app/public/Users/tolga/Desktop/project-path/storage/image
```

Resized images under this location are empty files actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aro mentioned, I removed storage_path from Storage:put method, but than I realized that I actually don't need this line, with Intervention.

I first added as alias:

```
'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
    'Image' => Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic::class,
```

Than, as a one liner code:

```
use Image;

...

Image::make(storage_path('app/public/image/' . $uniqueFileName))->fit(200, 200)->save();
```

This resizes as a square, even the image file is not square and than saves with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't generate a path with `storage_path` if you are using `Storage facade`, because   `storage_path` will generate an absolute path, but `Storage facade` with `disk local or public` already knows the path to storage. So just write like this

```
  Storage::disk('public')->put('relative path in storage', $file);
```

Comment: thank you, now path problem is solved but resized images are still empty files.